# Put several outputs into one list

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

I'm trying to segment a license plate into characters and recognize them one by one
first this code segment the license plate into characters but i don't know how to put this characters into a list so that i can iterate over that list and do the recognition task using a model i made

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
segmentation_spacing = 0.93
img = cv2.imread('img.png')
img_gray = cv2.imread('img.png',0)
#img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
ret, img_threshold = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
white = []  
black = []  
height,width = img_gray.shape
##height = 216#img_threshold.shape[0]
##width = 915#img_threshold.shape[1]
white_max = 0
black_max = 0
for i in range(width):
    white_count = 0
    black_count = 0
    for j in range(height):
        if img_threshold[j][i] == 255:
            white_count += 1
        else:
            black_count += 1

    white.append(white_count)
    black.append(black_count)

white_max = max(white)
black_max = max(black)
def find_end(start):
    end = start + 1
    for m in range(start + 1, width - 1):
        if(black[m] > segmentation_spacing * black_max):
            end = m
            break
    return end
n = 1
start = 1
end = 2
while n < width - 1:
    n += 1
    if(white[n] > (1 - segmentation_spacing) * white_max):
        start = n
        end = find_end(start)
        n = end
        if end - start > 5:
            print(start, end)
            character = img[1:height, start:end]
            output = [cv2.imwrite('img/{0}.png'.format(n), character)      ]
            #cv2.imshow('character', character)
            cv2.waitKey(0)
            cv2.destroyAllWindows() ``
```

Comment: Hi! Welcome to SO! `character = img[1:height, start:end]` - Is this the line where you are extracting the character? If so, do you want this character in a list, along with the rest of the characters?

Comment: thanks for answering , but i did the work by converting characters into numpy arrays then in one list so i can iterate over them